# Load data onto landing page from a REST api using Interceptor Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I want to show the data on the home page from a REST api (need authorization 'username' and 'password' to access) using Interceptor in Angular 6. However, previously I had used Node.js to fetch the data and it was pretty successful at that time. Moreover, when I switch to the Interceptor it shows the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:6)
at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:70)
at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:67)
at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:50)
at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
at Observable._subscribe (scalar.js:5)
at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
at MergeMapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js:28)
```

In my solution, I have created a function in the landing component which is like this:

```js
const userData = { username: 'anonymous', password: '' };

this.http
  .post(`${this.baseURL}/auth/jwt/authenticate`, userData)
  .subscribe(res => {
    // console.log(res);
    const token = JSON.parse(res['_body']).token;
    this.publicToken = token;
    if (token) {
      this.publicTokenStatusListener.next(true);
      localStorage.setItem('public-token', token);
    }
  });
```

The Interceptor is like this:

```js
intercept(
        req: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

const authToken = localStorage.getItem('public-token');

        
const copiedReq = req.clone({
    params: req.params.set('auth', authToken)
});

return next.handle(copiedReq);

}
```

From the service, I am returning the REST data (GET) to fetch the observable. However, it doesn't work as I am expecting.

I can get the 'token' in the Interceptor. Waiting for some suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder if you should be setting `headers`, rather that `params`, when you are cloning the request. Something to [try](https://angular.io/guide/http#set-default-headers)?

Comment: Hi @R.Richards, thanks a lot for your comment. I have tried with the headers also. However, the result still the same.

Comment: please provide full code part with `imports` for `interceptor` and also `providers` part of main `@NgModule`

Answer (score 0):

> **HttpParams** is [immutable](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#description).

You need to use `setParams` instead of `params`:

```
const copiedReq = req.clone({
    setParams: {'auth': authToken}
});
```

Are you sure that ***sensitive*** data should be passed as `params`?

Might be it would be better to use `headers`?